# How to insert image along with text in MySql?

Tags: mysql, tinymce

I am trying to prepare a sample question paper preparation app.
I am using tinyMCE editor and ajax-file-uploader plugin with it - as some questions may need images along with text.
How do I store my questions that have both image and text into MySql using PhP?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest storing the image on some sort of NAS or some other location, and store the path to the image in the database along with the other data in respective fields.

You can store the image in the DB but it is not good idea to retrieve and present the image from the database to the user (It doesn't perform that great either). There might be a performance hit

Comment: Thanks @harigm for a very prompt reply. Yup. Agreed that there might be a performance hit if i store images in DB. Will store them in a separate folder as you suggested. I have one more question.. Can we store both image and text in a single blob field ?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL handles images very well. You insert them in BLOBs. On the other hand you could store the image file name and path or a link, as text in your DB.

Which solution is the best depends on the requirements of your application. In general if you have a huge amount of images, your database will become huge and backing up will be slow. There might be a similar impact on your file system in order to store a huge amount of images.

Here is the interesting Microsoft [To BLOB or not to BLOB](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64525/tr-2006-45.pdf) paper, that will give you more information on the topic and even some metrics.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link @Costis. One more question.. Can I share both image and text in a single blob field in mysql ?

Comment: I would save the text in a Varchar field called "description" or whatever. This way you avoid merging and extracting algorithms that would slow you down unnecessarily. This will allow you additionally to search for images through description.

Answer (score 0):

I would echo the answers already given by @harigm and @Costis Aivalis but if you really wanted to go "all out" and store both the HTML content and the images in the same BLOB why not have a look at RFC 2557 which allows you to place binary data (like images) in the document itself using the url scheme `data:`. To make this work you will need to parse your HTML once it gets back to your server and base64 encode all the images to be placed in the HTML, quite a lot of work for what would probably turn out to be little reward.

Comment: I found this page: http://rifers.org/blogs/gbevin/2005/4/11/embedding_images_inside_html that explains this quite nicely and means you do not have to read an RFC.